# Nodejs app is starting everyday and eating up memory

Tags: upstart, nodejs

I was trying to run ghost node.js application on my ubuntu server. Since I am mostly experimenting with linux systems I have tried a bunch of things and finally managed to make ghost run on server restart using forever package and the following upstart script.

```
description     "node.js ghost aps"

start on started
stop on shutdown

script
        export PATH="/home/deploy/local/bin:$PATH"
        export NODE_ENV=production
        cd "/home/deploy/web-apps/ghost/"
        exec forever start "/home/deploy/web-apps/ghost/index.js" -e "/home/deploy/web-apps/ghost/error.log"
end script
```

But after sometime I noticed that the number of running scripts is increasing everyday and eventually causing out of memory errors.

```
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command                     script                                                                        forever pid  logfile                 uptime
data:    [0] unyu /home/deploy/local/bin/node /home/deploy/web-apps/ghost/index.js -e /home/deploy/web-apps/ghost/error.log 530     752  /root/.forever/unyu.log 2:22:4:30.155
data:    [1] 73wG /home/deploy/local/bin/node /home/deploy/web-apps/ghost/index.js -e /home/deploy/web-apps/ghost/error.log 2563    2573 /root/.forever/73wG.log 0:23:31:55.579
```

How and where should I check to see what is starting these scripts?

Comment: There was 3 scripts running at first but I stopped the one in the middle before I post the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by changing `start on started` to `start on startup`